# How to keep Grunt dom_munger from stripping your CDN dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, plaid

I have an object, `Plaid`, that is provided by a drop-in module from [Plaid](https://www.plaid.com/docs/), called [Plaid Link](https://github.com/plaid/link). Locally, the code works perfectly in my AngularJS front-end.

The module is loaded via my AngularJS app's index.html file, right next to all of the other script tags loaded for my application.

**Index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
```

**Here is the code where `Plaid` is called:** *(from an AngularJS controller)*

```
$scope.addAccount = function(bankChosen) {

    $log.debug("Plaid object: ", Plaid);
    var linkHandler = Plaid.create({ // the troublesome line 
        env: 'tartan',
        clientName: 'Example Project',
        key: 'test_key',
        product: 'connect',
        onSuccess: function(public_token) {
            Restangular.one('plaid').customPOST(
                {
                    public_token: public_token,
                    user_id: $scope.currentUser.id,
                    institution_code: bankChosen
                },
                'addAccount'
            );
        },
        onExit: function() {
            $state.go('dashboard.successState');
        },
    });

    linkHandler.open(bankChosen);

};
```

However, when I push to the production environment, currently hosted on Heroku, it gives the javascript error `ReferenceError: Plaid is not defined` when it tries to load. It is breaking error when deployed to production.

**What could be causing this module to be unavailable during production?**

The script that loads the CDN could be getting stripped away by a standard grunt task that does that sort of thing? Or maybe I am supposed to be loading the module from the CDN in some other way in a production-environment setting? I really don't know...

**Update: I found one thing that might be stripping the loaded module**

From the [Grunt dom-munger docs](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger)

> Use this task to read and transform your HTML documents. Typical use cases include:
>
> 1. Read the references from your script or link tags and pass those to
>      concat,uglify, etc automatically.
>
> **2. Update HTML to remove script
>   references or anything that is not intended for your production
>   builds.**
>
> 3. Add, update, or remove any DOM elements for any reason.

`dom_munger` is part of my application's build process, which happens when it is deployed (!). Grunt is the likely culprit here.

**Does anybody know how to load the script tag above, with dom_munger as still part of my app's grunt build step?**

Comment: Can you provide a plunker demo?

Comment: If your `Plaid` object is not loaded, you should not refer to it. Just check it conditionally before you call.

Comment: Well, in that case I would need to figure out how to load it. @Joy It loads automatically when I run the same code locally...

Comment: Check Chrome dev panel to see whether it is loaded correctly.

Comment: I'll try to make a plunker demo in a minute @StaffordWilliams

Comment: figured this out! StackOverflow won't let me accept my answer yet but I'll post it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that during the build step Grunt strips away the script tags in my application. So I had to `append` the tag back on to my body tag using `dom_munger`'s update --> options --> append option.

...only then could I get the CDN script to be linked to properly after the app was built using `grunt build`.

The line looks like this in my Gruntfile.

```
--> The key added line is this one
{selector:'body',html:'<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>'},


dom_munger:{
    [.....]
  update: {
    options: {
      append: [
        {selector:'body',html:'<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>'},
      ]
    },
    src:'index.html',
    dest: 'dist/index.html'
  }
```

Quite the mysterious error for me. I hope this helps somebody else out at some point!